# How can i fix the problem with aiohttp or aiogram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp, pytest-aiohttp

aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError: Aiohttp client throws error: ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl: default [Semaphore timeout exceeded]
I had this error when i was running the code of my telegram bot. Then, I installed the aiohttp again. And it has gone. But here is another problem. When i run the code of telegram bot, bot is not working. He doesnt answer to my commands, but there is no error in console.
No error - but bot doesnt work.
Can someone help me with this problem please? I appreciate any advices and tips. Python-3.8v

Code:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import time
from time import sleep
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import asyncio
bot = Bot('token')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_message(message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'some text')
```

Comment: Can you please add your code snippet, so that we can see it?

Comment: i have edited the post. can you check it out and help me.

Answer (score 1):

First, you run `python <program>` in your terminal with a command like

```
python test1.py
```

In terminal you got message

```
INFO:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Start polling....
```

Second, you need to go to Telegram app, to your bot chat. And write comands, like `/start`.